# Is the Google "zerg rush" easter egg on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[Is it possible to beat Google's zerg rush easter egg game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64300/is-it-possible-to-beat-googles-zerg-rush-easter-egg-game)

I downvoted and voted to close this question. I don't think it belongs on the site. Others may disagree.

Should questions about this thing be allowed on the main site? Why or why not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I feel that these are on topic and should not be closed or downvoted for the sole reason that they are either too simple or related to a Google Doodle/Easter Egg.  (Obviously it's possible to ask a close- or downvote-worthy question about this subject, as it is possible on any subject)

For instance, [Pac-Man](http://www.google.com/pacman/) is a previous doodle, and I'd say that questions about Pac-Man, or the Google Doodle variant, would be on topic.  Note that I just liked an old doodle that's not on the front page of Google anymore - they're archived, and therefore I don't think "too localized" applies.  Previous easter eggs such as [do a barrel roll](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-a-barrel-roll) are still valid, despite being months old.

There are many simple flash games around the internet, and I don't think it makes sense to say this is "too simple to be a game" - there are plenty of valid questions for even the simplest games.

With regard to this game in particular, there are a ton of games similar to this, where you must react to some element on the screen by clicking it, and failing too often leads to game over.  [Ant Crusher](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTpldq3myV0) for iOS, for example.  Heck, even [Missile Command](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-cD0XdyQ7s) is an arguably similar experience.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that it is on topic for now, but if it happens to not get archived in the near future and the topic somehow becomes active again, then I would say close it as *too localized*.

Answer (score -10):

I am not trying to generate a blanket rule here: this pertains only to Google's "zerg rush" Easter egg.

**This thing should not be in the valid topic space for Gaming.**

Possible reasons:

- It's not even a game (don't argue the minutiae of the definition of the word game with me)
- It's not deep enough, as an activity, for expertise to be meaningful
- It's not meant to be played as a game; it's meant to be playful, short-lived fun
- ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Your argument is based on the minutiae of the definition of "game", so telling us not to argue that is a bit counterproductive.  I certainly don't see a disparity between "playful, short-lived fun" and "gaming"; I don't even think it's minutiae.

Comment: **Downvoting** is for things you don't like.  Ruling things off-topic based on dislike would be ridiculous.  I think if you want to go with a "I know whether it's a game when I see it" sort of thing instead of making rules about it that are argued, I don't see the point of making this post.  VTC, let others vote as they see fit, let it resolve naturally.